# Return a value in React Table

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an API that returns integers for an ID field. The API returns an array of objects

I'd like to lookup that ID in array and return the corresponding description in a table cell.

What's the best way to do this?

Example data is:

```
const demo = [{ "id": 1, "code": "AUD"}, {"id": 2, "code": "USD"]
```

I map through the API results to get each object as a row. In each row is an "id" field that I want to lookup.

I'd like to display in the `Tablecell` the corresponding "code" of that ID but unsure best way to handle that. For example - if an object returns "id": 1, rather than display 1 in table, I'd like to show "AUD".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ps, Show use your `HTML`, demo to help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: Plz show the example image you want

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the corresponding value in an array you can use the find() method. The ternary operator checks to see if the id is in the array and if not it returns "id not found".

```
function LookUp(props) {
  const demo = [{ "id": "1", "code": "AUD"}, {"id": "2", "code": "USD"}, {"id": "3", "code": "EURO"}];
  
  const Atest = () => {
    const ans = demo.some(e => e.id === props.id) ? demo.find(x => x.id === props.id).code : "id not found"
    return(ans);
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Atest />
    </div>
  );
}

function App(){
  return (
    <>
    <LookUp id="4" />   
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I implemented this and I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined".. Any ideas what that would be? Cheers

Comment: If you're getting that error then either: (a) the array (demo in the example) hasn't been defined or (b) you're trying to access an id that hasn't been defined in the array for example in my code if you changed the lookup to LookUp id="4" in the App then it would return that error.

Comment: I added a check to see if the id is in the array.